# Asynchronous Call Issue with Spring Cloud Gateway and Feign Client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-feign

I'm facing an issue with my Spring Cloud Gateway setup where a GET endpoint, configured to traverse multiple services, is not waiting for responses from downstream services. Specifically, I have a Spring Cloud Gateway service, registered with **Consul** as a discovery client, that routes requests to a **portfolio-service**. This **portfolio-service** then makes use of a Feign Client to call an endpoint in the **risk-profiler-service**.

below predicate I'm using for routing.

```
routes:
    - id: portfolioservice
      uri: lb://portfolioservice
      predicates:
        - Path=${gateway-prefix}/v1/riskManagers/**
      filters:
        - RewritePath=${gateway-prefix}/(?<path>.*), ${gateway-prefix}/$\{path}          
        - name: CircuitBreaker
          args:
            name: portfolioServiceFallback
            fallbackuri: forward:/fallback/portfolioServiceFallback
```

also, I added the below properties in the application.yml file

```
spring:
   cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        config:
          default:
            readTimeout: 600000
            connectTimeout: 600000
```

How can I ensure that the Spring Cloud Gateway waits for responses from nested services, especially when using a Feign Client within a service?

Any insights, recommendations, or examples on how to properly configure such a setup would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add response timeout in gateway like so

```
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.response-timeout=700s
```

Comment: I already added:
    spring:
         cloud:
           gateway:
              httpclient:   
                 connect-timeout: 600000
                 response-timeout: 600000